# Artificial Neural Network not learming

Tags: java

Here is my code over GitHub, [RNA Repository](https://github.com/ceciliassis/rna-ufu-2016/tree/master/RNA/src/RNA).

The thing is: my activation function is not returning the expected values and the output is often (almost always) the same, like everybody getting the same classification, I dont know what I'm doing wrong, but I'm pretty sure that's everything.

I'm a newbie in Neural Network so I'm not using matrix like most of the codes that I've seen, **can somebody please help me?
Any doubts please, let me know.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, for anybody that's interested, i've done it -> https://github.com/ceciliassis/UFU/tree/master/MD/RedeNeural